# Как обработать определённые значения memcache?

Tags: memcache, php

Добрый день.

Я вношу в кеш с ключами people_1111, people_1112,people_1113..., а также data_1111, data_1112,data_1113...

Мне нужно выбрать значения только относительно people_ и произвести с каждым из них вычисления либо получить массив ключ/значение.

Как это реализовать?
Спасибо.

Comment: @Роман Ракзин Нет, нельзя. В Redis [можно](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis#keys-getkeys).

    $redis->keys('people_*');

Answer (score 1):

Легко!

```
$cm = new Memcached("SERVER_ID");
$cm->addServer("127.0.0.1", 11211);
$all_keys = $cm->getAllKeys();
foreach ($all_keys as $k) {
    if (preg_match("/^people_(\d+)/", $k, $matches) == 1 ) {
        $p_key = $matches[1];
        // делаем что должно
    }
}

$all_cache = getMulti($all_keys);
var_dump($all_cache);
```

Должны стоять следующие пакеты:

```
dpkg -l | grep memc
ii  memcached
ii  php5-memcached
ii  libmemcached10
```

Comment: @boris_U, а если записей  будет миллион?

Да, и что это за индусский код?

    if (preg_match("/^people_(\d+)/", $k, $matches) == 1 )

Comment: @romeo: а если не будет миллион? Это второй вопрос. 

Концептуально проблема решаема.

Что не так с этим кодом?

Comment: > Концептуально проблема решаема.

Неверное решение.

> Что не так с этим кодом?

   if (preg_match("/^people_(\d+)/", $k, $matches)) {
      ....
   }

@boris_U, про нелогичное наименование переменных я уже и не говорю.

    $cm -> $memcached    
    $all_keys -> $keys 
    $k -> $key    
    $all_cache -> $users

Comment: @romeo: то есть по существу возразить нечего?